# Using Gimp; which is the best method for removing the text from this image

Tags: inkscape, gimp

Heal selection? This is the one I think might work best but not sure and would like to know if others agree.

I searched the various methods used to remove text from images and found one I thought might work best but I couldn't comment on the post to ask (something about not having enough points?) So if I am repeating the question, I apologize, but I really do need to know which way works best without going through all the trials and tribulations process, as I am pressed for time. My end result should preserve all background content, remove text only, new text will be written over it. I have the SVG format and PNG, I'm working with Gimp and Inkscape. Both are current version to date (09/27/2020).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes heal selection will work, however because there isn't a lot of plain background around the text, you may have to run it a couple of times. With a bit of experimentation, a second pass may not be required. Possibly changing the sampling width to around 25 instead of 50 would help get it to work better.

First pass, I get this. No settings were changed, just hit OK

[image]

Then I did a second pass with a smaller selection to remove the parts that got left behind.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I made an error when posting my question though. I am using Gimp to edit and so resynthesizer is the method/plugin I should have mentioned, instead of the  heal selection tool. It is my understanding the 2 work in very much the same way though. I'll go ahead and try it out. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @NeekkeeN - yes this is Resynthesizer in GIMP, with the Heal Selection plugin.  I used the version available at the [link shown here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Resynthisizer-Heal-Selection-Runtime-Error?pid=12687#pid12687) on the GIMP forum

Answer (score 1):

Content-aware Fill…

Run a rough lasso round the words, Edit > Content Aware Fill

Done.

[image]

D'oh… Gimp, not Photoshop.
I'll leave this here in case it's useful to anyone else in future

Answer (score 1):

This one needs only the basic tools. Make a fuzzy selection (magic wand) of the text:

[image]

Fill the selection with somehow average color of the area between the letters. It unfortunately leaves 1px wide edge ghosts and the color is exactly right only in few places.

Make a new selection which covers the background except the decorative stripes at the top right corner:

[image]

Apply Median Blur to the selection. The radius should be tried with the sliders. The result:

[image]